# Is it possible to express a closure taking a mutable reference with a higher-rank lifetime with BoxFnOnce?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

A `Box`ed `FnOnce` is currently [not callable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28796) in Rust. As a workaround, I am using the [boxfnonce](https://github.com/stbuehler/rust-boxfnonce) crate, which attempts to mimic the functionality.

The `boxfnonce` crate exports a struct `BoxFnOnce<'a, (A, B...), R>`, which functions the way `Box<dyn FnOnce(A, B...) -> R + 'a>` would if it worked.

The problem is that I want one of the arguments to my boxed closure to be a mutable reference whose lifetime is elided. Were I using a boxed `FnOnce`, I could simply write:

```
type Foo<T> = Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut T)>;
```

and this would be desugared into the higher-ranked lifetime

```
Box<dyn for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut T)>
```

because the `Fn` traits are magical. The problem is that `BoxFnOnce` is neither magical, nor even a trait, so when I write

```
type Foo<T> = BoxFnOnce<(&mut T,)>;
```

Rust wants me to give the reference a lifetime.

The compiler's suggestion is to add a lifetime parameter to `Foo`:

```
type Foo<'a, T> = BoxFnOnce<(&'a mut T,)>;
```

but this doesn't seem right, since we want the closure to be callable on *any* choice of reference lifetime, not a specific one. I'd prefer not to have to switch to nightly if possible.

Comment: **Update:** since there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, I ultimately just switched to nightly and used `FnBox`.

Comment: And you can't use `FnMut(T)` instead of `FnOnce(&mut T)`?

Comment: @PeterHall `FnMut(T)` doesn't let you modify `T`, and some of the relevant closures move captured variables, so I can only require `FnOnce`.

Comment: Doh! Stupid brain!